# Ionic 4: ion-chip activatable / clickable by default; how to turn off?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic4

Using Ionic 4 with React, I have the following code:

```js
<IonChip color="success">
  <IonIcon icon={thumbsUp} />
  <IonLabel>{this.state.numCorrect}</IonLabel>
</IonChip>
```

This by default is rendering the following DOM content in my browser:

```html
<ion-chip color="success" class="ion-color ion-color-success ios ion-activatable hydrated">
  <ion-icon role="img" class="ios hydrated"> ... </ion-icon>
  <ion-label class="sc-ion-label-ios-h sc-ion-label-ios-s ios hydrated">0</ion-label>
</ion-chip>
```

As you can see, the `ion-activatable` class is being automatically added to the chip component, which is causing it to appear clickable and show the Material Design ripple effect, etc. But I don't want this component to be clickable (I am using it just as an indicator component). Can I disable this class somehow?

The online documentation for Ionic 4 doesn't offer any advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [implemetation](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/chip/chip.tsx) of the `ion-chip` Webcomponent, you can see that the `ion-activatable` class is added by default (you can only modify the class and the events after the component is rendered):

```
export class Chip implements ComponentInterface {
  /**
   * The color to use from your application's color palette.
   * Default options are: `"primary"`, `"secondary"`, `"tertiary"`, `"success"`, `"warning"`, `"danger"`, `"light"`, `"medium"`, and `"dark"`.
   * For more information on colors, see [theming](/docs/theming/basics).
   */
  @Prop() color?: Color;

  /**
   * Display an outline style button.
   */
  @Prop() outline = false;

  render() {
    const mode = getIonMode(this);

    return (
      <Host
        class={{
          ...createColorClasses(this.color),
          [mode]: true,
          'chip-outline': this.outline,
          'ion-activatable': true,
        }}
      >
        <slot></slot>
        {mode === 'md' && <ion-ripple-effect></ion-ripple-effect>}
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

so a simple workaround you can do, is to prevent all click, state and cursor options on the `ion-chip` element with the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property (and only do `<IonChip mode="ios">` if you don't want the ripple efect to be rendered):

```css
ion-chip {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. I'm a bit disappointed that the Ionic 4 developers wouldn't expose this as a configurable property, and instead hard-coded it as true. Seems simple enough to expose...